# SGI hash_map: Basic Inquiries

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable, sgi

I am new to SGI's hash_map as well as to the C++ language, so please bear with me.
I am trying to figure out how to initialize a basic hash_map and insert and remove from it.

I have declared the hash_map as such:

```
Sgi::hash_map<int, Process*> ProcessManager::ListProcesses;
```

I intend to hash by an int value and store a pointer to an object of class Process.

However, the SGI documentation is very vague and unhelpful. I'm reading through the hash_map file but also not understanding much of it. Could someone show me the proper way to insert and erase from an SGI hash_map?

To be clear: What I'm looking for is a BASIC example to learn from.
Please and thank you!

Comment: Are you aware that C++ has its own version of a hash map -- [`std::unordered_map<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)? Why use SGI's?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do the following.

```
Sgi::hash_map<int, Process*> ListProcesses;

Process *p1; // Initialize these
Process *p2;

//Insertion
ListProcesses[10] = p1;  // new element inserted
ListProcesses[20] = p2;  // new element inserted

//Erase
ListProcesses.erase(20);  //(20,p2) deleted
```

As ildjarn commented, you can use [std::unordered_map<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_map/) instead of the SGI one.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the example in the [SGI docs](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html)?  It clearly shows how to declare a hash_map and how to add values to it.

```
hash_map<const char*, int, hash<const char*>, eqstr> months;

months["january"] = 31;
months["february"] = 28;
months["march"] = 31;
```

That variable `months` is a `hash_map` that uses keys of type `const char*` and maps them to values of type `int`, and because you don't want to compare the keys by comparing pointer values for equality, it uses a custom equality [functor](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/functors.html) called `eqstr` which says whether two `const char*` strings have the same contents.

To erase you use the `erase` member function, crazy eh.

`size_type erase(const key_type& k)`     Erases the element whose key is k.

So that would be:

```
months.erase("march");
```

The SGI docs are far from vague.

Comment: So in this: hash_map<const char*, int, hash<const char*>, eqstr> months;
Months is the name of the hashtable?
And we insert by doing months[whatever we want to insert]? and then the 31 is the number being hashed by (the key), or is it what is being stored as data?

Comment: Yes.  Seems like you're struggling with basic C++ grammar, not the SGI docs or `hash_map` in particular.